# How do you unregister snippets in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I can register the snippets...

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var snippetManager = ace.require("ace/snippets").snippetManager;
var snippetText = "snippet vfx\n\t<visalforce>\n\t\t$1\n\t</visalforce>";
var snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(snippetText);
snippetManager.register(snippets);

editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: false
});
```

But, the unregister just does not work and there is almost zero documentation or samples on the inter-webs...but I keep trying variations of this...

```
snippetText = "snippet vfx\n\t<visalforce>\n\t\t$1\n\t</visalforce>";
snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(snippetText);
snippetManager.unregister(snippets);
```

And it does not work. The snippets are still available in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you pass the same object for insert and remove, see this example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit();
  editor.container.style.height = "100px";
  document.body.append(editor.container);
  var snippetManager = ace.require("ace/snippets").snippetManager;
  var snippetText = "snippet vfx\n\t<visalforce>\n\t\t$1\n\t</visalforce>";
  var snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(snippetText);
  snippetManager.register(snippets);

  editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true
  });
  
  function removeSnippets() {
    snippetManager.unregister(snippets);
  }
  function addSnippets() {
    snippetManager.register(snippets);
  }
</script>

<button onclick=removeSnippets()>remove snippets</button>
<button onclick=addSnippets()>add snippets</button>
```

Comment: Uggg, I figured out what it was. I was reading the snippet file in again and creating another snippets object for the unregister. That did not work. But when I used the exact same snippets object created and used originally for the register, then it works. So, the snippets object has to be the exact same object not an object hydrated from the same snippets file.